# Is Helvetica considered a "web safe" font?

Tags: css, font

Should I consider the font [Helvetica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica) to be a [web-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web-safe_fonts) font, i.e. is it a reliable source to set in my [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) that will be accessible on any device?

Comment: How is this a UX question? Shouldn't it be on [GraphicDesign.StackExchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) or something similar?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Not only is Helvetica not safe, but it is also a **copyrighted font**, so you need a license to use it if you load it as webfont.

As a matter of fact, **there are no 100% safe web fonts**, since it will depend on the fonts the user have on his/her device, and different operative systems have different font sets. Hence, you need to do something like this:

```
p{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
```

Otherwise, your site will be visualized with the default font the user has set , for example, *Times New Roman*.

If you want to play safe, I recommend this quite nifty resource: [CSS Font Stack](http://www.cssfontstack.com). There you can see *"safer"* fonts, percentage of usage by OS and even the code to use including *fallback* alternatives

Comment: Yes, you're correct, editing accordingly :)

Comment: Why not just `font-family: sans-serif`? It works great everywhere: Including email clients.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, because that is a fallback, but you may want to actually have the font you actually intended to have whenever possible, specially if you use webfonts

Comment: I understand that it is a fallback, but, sometimes, the `font: sans-serif` looks (subjectivelly) better than Arial or Helvetica.

Comment: sorry, but UX is not about randomness, but about control. You may like it better *sometimes*, but it is purely subjective as you say, and certainly not something to recommend

Comment: @Devin very true, I like to use Roboto on my sites, settling for the random sans-serif will give a completely different experience than what I intended.

Comment: @Devin I agree. While mentioning the font in Css, it should be changed as p{font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}. Primary font should come first if stakeholders prefer this font and next we need to add system fonts like Arial n sansarif

Comment: Why all the comments about copyrights and loading webfonts? The question asks about web-safe fonts that (by definition) are already present on the device of the end-user. The question expresses no wish to load webfonts.

Comment: @GrafixGuru Indeed. Arial is, after all, just a cheap copy of Helvetica. Ask for Helvetica, fall back to Arial and not the other way around.

Comment: You can also use something like [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) to ensure that a specific font is used, but you may find the selection somewhat limited since it's a free service.  You could also serve WOFF files yourself, I suppose, but check with your lawyer first.

Comment: CSS Font Stack is nice but it only shows fonts installed on desktop Windows and OS X.

Comment: Some good read about Helvetica in Windows. [Link](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/windows-subs-helvetica-arial)

Comment: C'mon, there are free (and legal) clones of Helvetica, see e.g. TeX Gyre Heros. So if you want to use Helvetica as your font, you can. You just have to provide it of course ("embed it")

Comment: Your first sentence is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: CSS Font Stack doesn't list Comic Sans, it's totally useless to me now!!! *kidding*

Comment: @Jeff I know the question asked if it a web safe font. So I was hesitant to post my own answer addressing web fonts. However there was no indication the asker was aware of web fonts and since the knowledge could only help them I figured it wouldn't hurt to make a mention.

Comment: Don't quite get the CSS Font Stack site. It claims that Impact has a 0 % "compatability" on Windows. But I have never seen a Windows machine without Impact, nor have I ever seen this spelling of "compatibility".

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned there is no such thing as a safe web font. But there is a way to load in missing fonts from your server through the use of [@font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/). @font-face was first introduced in CSS2, includes fallback file types, and is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface). This wouldn't be a 100% solution but it would be more promising than depending on the machine's font selection.

First you would put the file on your server as a regular static hosted file. You might have to configure your web server's mime types so it properly handles the file and doesn't attempt to make the client manual download it instead.

Then you would implement code in your stylesheet that looks like the following. Take note these are just some of the possible formats. You are not required to use all of them. But if you are not delete the reference to the file to avoid an unnecessary delay caused by the missing resource.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

After which you would assign the font to your element. If you wanted to attempt to use your version of the Helvetica use something like:

```
font-family: 'MyWebFont', Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

If the font-face cannot be loaded it will attempt to use the machine's Helvetica and if that fails it will attempt load sans-serif. Additionally you can swap your font and the machine font around. But it won't save your bandwidth because it will still load your fonts once it loads the stylesheet.

Last but most importantly Helvetica is not a free font. You will need to buy a license for its usage. Linotype will sell you the necessary web fonts and license from their website. Pricing is based on page views. But once purchased it is completely legal to embed in your webpage or web app.

Answer (score 10):

Helvetica is not part of any Windows default font-set, therefore Windows users are likely to see another secondary font. If that's not a concern for you, use Helvetica.

Comment: The Arial font is standard on all versions of Windows (since v3.1) and has essentially the same layout characteristics; using Arial as a fallback for Helvetica will thus give substantially the same look and feel (said with due apologies to those font enthusiasts who know and care about the differences). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial

Comment: Windows iss not the only OS, don't forget about everyone else. Others might not have Arial.

Comment: Arial is not there by default in many linux distros, for instance.

Answer (score 10):

> be accessible on any device

Really no such thing as 'available on *any* device'.

If you're not using embedded fonts, then you need to use a font-stack, so you have some back up options in case the first isn't available.